# Paul Darrow (Blake 7's Kerr Avon), RIP

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

https://www.telegraph.co.uk/obituaries/2019/06/04/paul-darrow-actor-cherished-science-fiction-fans-role-sardonic/

Kerr Avon was one of the best antihero characters in science fiction.  Darrow was sublime in the role.

[image]

Comment: I only knew the name Kerr Avon thanks to [this fellow](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/55249/kerr-avon). When I started watching *Blakes 7* last year, I realised he was a sci-fi character, and perhaps the most fitting one for an SFF.SE user to name themselves after.

Comment: My favourite character from probably my all time favourite Scifi show.

Comment: Paul Darrow was brilliant as Avon.  I loved the show as a teen and still love it today - mainly because of Avon, Cally and Vila (and Servalan).  The series main hero, Blake, was acted well by Gareth Thomas, but it was Avon who stole the show.  Interestingly, I also enjoyed his prequel book (Avon: A Terrible Aspect).  Rest in Peace, Paul.

Comment: I loved BLAKES 7. Paul Darrow's commitment to the character of Avon was incredible and has left an indelible shape in my memory. In anyone's else's hands it would have been pure pantomine, but he made made it terrifying, elegiac and exciting. An object lesson in how to turn something mundane into something extraordinary.

Comment: I and a couple of friends interviewed him years ago. A really nice, humble chap with a good sense of humour. He was terrific as Avon. Anti-hero personified.

Answer (score 1):

> I have never understood why it should be necessary to become irrational in order to prove that you care. Or indeed why it should be necessary to prove it at all.

Always shield the top of your gun with your left hand while aiming it. Remember the man who produced the most acerbic remarks in the galaxy, the only man who could take a show named after a charismatic character and keep it going without that character. Always destined to be the last man standing.

[image]

(I just now finished watching the incredible finale of *Blake's 7*, and came back to post this. Capable, compelling, captivating, and completely unflappable right up to the last instant of the show, Kerr Avon is one of the most memorable characters in sci-fi.)

Comment: One of the most jaw-dropping endings to a series I've ever seen. Did NOT see it coming!

Comment: @HelbentIV I'd been sufficiently spoiled by the internet to know approximately how the series ends, but I was *still* shocked and gutpunched when I watched it. Specifically Avon's part.

Comment: @HelbentIV I didn't put it in the answer because spoilers, but [you might like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvUfVUPrhZA).